# Javascript Array 'Literal' - Is that just describing how its created since it can be changed on the fly?

Tags: javascript, literals

I don't understand why Mozilla calls this an Array 'Literal' when it's defined using the VARIABLE keyword and it can be completely changed...

`var coffees = ["French Roast", "Colombian", "Kona"];`

Can anyone explain this to me?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Object_literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The written, [literal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28computer_programming%29) `["French Roast", "Colombian", "Kona"]` actually *can't* be changed -- it's an array with those exact three strings, and nothing else. Once the literal is stored in a variable, the value of the variable can change, so the variable is non-literal.

You can even change the value of the structure represented by the literal on the fly, e.g., `[1,2,3].push(4)`, but even so, the *written value* of `[1,2,3]` is a literal that refers to an array with those three elements.

It's much like using numeric literals, e.g.,in `a = 1 + 2` the expressions `1` and `2` are unchangeable literals, but they can be combined to produce new results (and obviously the value of `a` can change).

Comment: This makes perfect sense.  I hope it's true!  I'm going to mark it as the answer unless I find out otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing literal and constant.

A constant doesn't change, but a literal just means you are explicitly setting the array values as a whole.

In other words, you are defining what you *literally* want the array value to be.  The literal itself (on the right side) is constant, but you are assigning it to a variable.  In the same way you could assign the value of a constant to a variable.

There are literals for pretty much every data type.

```
var myNumber = 42;                         // Number literal
var myString = "Thanks for all the fish";  // String literal
var myObject = { dolphins: 1, humans: 2 }; // Object literal
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a literal because you use the square brackets `var arr = [];` to initialize the array as opposed to using `var arr = new Array();`

It's the same way `{}` is a literal for objects

A literal is an opposition to a constructor and is simply a convenient language construct.

If you google "literals vs constructors" you will find quite a few pages regarding the subject :)

You can also read more on js literals here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Literals

Answer (score 1):

The term "literal" just means "here is the array, right here, the whole thing". A non-literal way of creating the same array could be:

```
var coffees = new Array();
coffees.push("French Roast");
coffees.push("Colombian");
coffees.push("Kona");
```

Comment: Although, in reality, you are using an empty literal to create the array, and then filling it.

Comment: "here is the array, right here, the whole thing".  BUT I can delete or add to this array later, correct?

Comment: @toddv: Yes, the literal array is just a starting point for your `coffees` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason the term *array literal* gets brought up is that creating an array using the `[]` literal or the `Array()` constructor is not *guaranteed* to produced the same results all of the time. This is because the `Array()` constructor could be altered or even replaced by a script. Consider this example:

```
Array = function() {
    var n = 0;

    for (var i=0, l=arguments.length; i<l; i++) {
        n += arguments[i];
    }

    return n;
}

var myArray = Array(1,2,3); // myArray type is number, value 6, probably not what you'd want
```

Versus

```
var myArray = [1,2,3]; // myArray type is object, value [1,2,3], probably what you'd want
```

So in addition to the literal syntax being more concise, it is also 100% predicable.